# What is obj folder generated for?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the obj and bin folders (created by Visual Studio) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for)

The default output path for any project is Visual studio is **`bin/Debug`**, but I have noticed that `obj` folder is also generated which again contains `dll` and `pdb` files. Can someone tell me why is this folder generated?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

"obj" folder is used to store temporary object files and other files used to create the final binary.

Further reading [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/456ebb0e-6fa3-4a77-a723-6984c5208562/)