# Purpose of the obj directory

Tags: .net

A simple question (hopefully).  What is the obj directory for in .NET?  I mean the directory that is generated besides the bin directory when a build occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `obj` directory is where the compiled object files are created and assembled into assemblies. In essence this is the working directory of the compiler/linker/assembler.

The results get copied to the `bin` (binary) directory.

Also See [What are the obj and bin folders (created by Visual Studio) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5308491/1583)

Answer (score 1):

The "obj" folder is used to store temporary object files and other files used in order to create the final binary during the compilation process.

The "bin" folder is the output folder for complete binaries (assemblies).