# where to find object code of my c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am going for copyright my application which requires source code & object code.
So can anybody tell me that where are they located & how can i find these codes?
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: This depends on your project settings. If you view them, it can tell you where they are.

Comment: @crashmstr in which section do i get it? i mean by what name?

Answer (score 1):

Your source code is the code you have written. This is stored wherever you've chosen to store you solution file. I believe the default location is:

```
C:\Users\{user}\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\{Project folder}
```

Your object code is the output from building your application. When you build in Visual Studio, the files are put into a \obj folder in the same location as your source code.

Here is a pretty good basic explanation of the two states of code: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/object-code

Comment: ohk got it but if i wish to read these files then can i read them via any text viewer? or for copyright i should copy these into a disk

Comment: You'll be able to read the source code in any text viewer. The object code will not be legible in any way.

Answer (score 0):

[Project Directory]\obj\ for the compiled, but not linked code and

[Project Directory]\bin\ for the compiled and linked code.

I imagine that you're looking for the latter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to this [What are the obj and bin folders (created by Visual Studio) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for)

Also if you click on a project and press the top button "Show all files" you will be able to see and access those files.