# vshost.exe still running after uncheck Enable the Visual Studio hosting process in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vshost.exe

I have a problem with the vshost.exe on running my test cases using a standalone test runner. vshost.exe is still running after I've done the following:

1. Clear my bin/Debug folder of the project.
2. Uncheck the "**Enable the Visual Studio hosting process**".
3. Restart Visual Studio.
4. Build the project.
5. Run test runner.

[image]

What else do I miss to kill the vshost.exe. Your response is truly appreciated.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you forgot to turn it off for the Release configuration.

Comment: hello @HansPassant. can i ask for steps in doing it. I'm a newbie for doing this. sorry.

Comment: @Airmovz what's the path to the running `vshost` - does it reside in the debug or release path? you can check this with Sysinternals `procexp`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev it is in the debug.

Answer (score 0):

From [comment56995746](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624462/vshost-exe-still-running-after-uncheck-enable-the-visual-studio-hosting-process?noredirect=1#comment56995746_34624462), my guesses are you either

- didn't save the settings, or
- didn't *rebuild,* rather than build, the project

  - that's because the compiled bits [actually reside in `obj` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for) (and then some are copied into `bin`) which you didn't clean. Rebuild makes VS disregard them.