# error in bin folder related to DLL conected with obj folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, bin

when am running my project 2 errors are coming first one is

> "Error    20  Could not copy "obj\Debug\graceCommunityCare-Nov2015.dll" to
>   "bin\graceCommunityCare-Nov2015.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10.
>   Failed".

and the second one is

> "Error    21  Unable to copy file
>   "obj\Debug\graceCommunityCare-Nov2015.dll" to
>   "bin\graceCommunityCare-Nov2015.dll". The requested operation cannot
>   be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open".

i have a `bin` folder with `gracecommunity DLL` and obj folder is comes automatic it is not included now .obj folder contain debug folder. In that folder there are dll and some other file so please help me to solve this problem.

2 images are attached please check u can understand easily...

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hREVC.jpg)

[error folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBndF.jpg)

Comment: please help me developers because am stuck with this problem..

Comment: Two images are attached u can see it by clicking error screenshot and error folder directory link

Comment: had you tried manually deleting the mentioned dlls?

Comment: ya i had tried to delete dll but i cant able to delete

Comment: restart your visual studio.

Comment: ya restarted visual studio but same error

Comment: make sure this dll: obj\Debug\graceCommunityCare-Nov2015.dll exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart your Visual Studio. Delete the obj and bin folders(If still you are not able to delete the bin and obj folders, restart your computer). 
Clean and re-compile the solution.

Comment: ya i close visual studio .then deleted bin and obj folders then restarted the visual studio .now it is running and the error is solved..thank u so much this is my first question in stackoverflow

Comment: Can u explain what is the use of bin and obj? how they are forming?how this error happened?

Comment: @Nidhin Please refer to the following link :
[obj and bin folders created by visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for)