# How to run c# project without 'obj' folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Somehow i did not receive obj folder of project, and i get an error "~\obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs"

is it possible to run project without OBJ folder, if so, how to do it?

Comment: You should not need obj folder for run or build process. Its temporary folder for building process.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for/5308538

Comment: you havent said what error?

Comment: @ErikŠťastný but it is still asking for temporar files from obj folder

Comment: @BugFinder can not find file _~\obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs_

Comment: @Nurik check answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have reproduced the problem easily.
I just deleted obj folder in my C# project solution.

When opening project in VS 2015 i got following:

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'D:\git-x\Server\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'D:\git-x\\Server\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'D:\git-x\Server\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
etc.
```

But this is absolutely **NOT** a blocking issue!!!

You can rebuild project or run .exe files from bin folder without any problem.
Obj folder is created again during build project process.