# Getting Error while building solution on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, azure-devops

I'm getting **Error CS0234** **(are you missing an assembly reference?)** on Server.
All files are working fine on my Local System (localhost) as well as on my peers' systems.
All the references have been added and Checked In in **TFS**.
can anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution.
I have noticed that we have a Total 10 Instance in Azure.
When the Main CI/CD pipeline builds it will dump all files in all instances.

When we have developed a new project we have configured it but the new CI/CD pipeline will dump code into 2 Instance of that new project.

And Gateway configuration has an error instead of diverting request to new project instance it's diverting to all other instance and at that time the new project assembly was not there so it will throw an exception.

1. Fixed CI/CD Pipeline
2. Fixed Gateway Configuration.

I think this will help people so sharing with you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not check-in the Reference in TFS. The references needs to be downloaded from Nuget Package during the build using `Nuget Restore command`

[image]

In some case you would want to checkin the reference- [See my answer here for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53248170/7073340)