# Correct way to deal with missing DLL when downloading Visual Studio Online project to different PC

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I downloaded the jsonUtils project from Github  https://github.com/bladefist/JsonUtils

It consists of a website and classlibrary.  The classlibrary has all the cool stuff I want in it.

I notice the top level folder of that solution contains Website, Classlibrary and Packages.

I built and run the the solution.  Works great.

I copied the classlibrary to my own solution where I need the functionality and did Add New... Existing Project and it's sitting pretty there.

[image]

I can make calls, get results and everything is hunky-dory.

Now I checked this all into VSO (Azure) and downloaded it on my different PC.

It won't compile on this PC and there is a missing reference.

[image]

System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.dll  is not found.

So I gone back to the PC where it works and "show all files" and in the bin folder I can see the missing files.

[image]

What is the correct way to deal with this?   One big difference is that I don't have the Packages folder containing the references that existing in the original github solution.

Comment: Might be [this one](https://github.com/CodeGator/CG.Pluralization).  Good reminder for everybody that re-using System names is a very bad practice.

Comment: @HansPassant no I think its the genuine one.  Also the Xamasoft.dll is missing.  Do I copy the packages folder from the source solution into mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's not suggest to check in /bin folder, dll files.

For some case, those DLL's wouldn't be available in Nuget.org or others.

> [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file specifies the
> untracked files.
> [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) defines
> attributes per path. They are configuration files of Git.
>
> In Visual Studio, the bin and obj folders are used to store the output
> generated by compilers (see
> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for)).
> As these output files are generated by compilers, you don't want to
> track them in the source control.
>
> If your project need to reference to some 3rd party dlls, the best
> approach is to reference to them as Nuget packages if there are Nuget
> packages available for the dlls. If not, **you can put them in a
> folder other than bin or obj so they can be tracked in Git.** You
> should not change .gitignore to track bin or obj folders.

You could also take a look at other's solution in this link: [Why does visual studio exclude BIN and OBJ folders at Azure DevOps checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246126/why-does-visual-studio-exclude-bin-and-obj-folders-at-azure-devops-checkin)

*Note:The ideal/best way of using 3rd part libraries is through NuGet Feed/Packages.*