# Why do I have this obj\Debug\TempPE folder after build? [not a duplicate, for sure]

Tags: c#, build

I am building a project using batch scripts that uses `msbuild.exe`. I performed two builds: a `manual` one and `automated` one.

The `manual` build resulted to this folder structure:

```
+ project
    + obj
        + Debug
        + Release
```

Meanwhile in `automated` build:

```
+ project
    + obj
        + Release
```

Can anyone explain how they got that difference? I am suspecting `nuget restoration` is the culprit for this but I don't have a proof for this or something.

As @vasily.sib suggested, this is just the script content:

```
cd msbuild_path
msbuild.exe project_path\project.sln /t:Clean;Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"
```

Comment: I guess this is because `automated` build is building only with `Release` configuration. But why do you ever care?

Comment: @vasily.sib why do I care? Someone's checking and comparing my build results and I need to come up with an explanation as to why is this happening

Comment: and as I have said up there, i am using scripts that uses `msbuild.exe`, additionally, I am specifying the configuration details in the script via `/p:Configuration=Release`

Comment: then maybe you will show us this batch scripts, so we will have an object to tallk about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if anyone will be having the same question in the future. I found out that the answer to this is very easy:

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5308538/10763029), `obj` folders are created during compilation. I realized that from the time I open my Visual Studio to restore my `NuGet package` in the `manual` build is also the time where `Debug` folder is created. The `automated` build restores `NuGet package` via script so it doesnt need to open Visual Studio.