# Visual studio which DLL to select when adding project references

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build, bin, project-reference

I'm really confused with all these different DLL files that can be used to add a project reference in Visual Studio.
After having clicked on '*Add Project Reference*', I choose for '*Browse*'. In the repository folder, there are two folders:

1. bin
2. obj

Inside the bin within directory '[RepoName]/bin/Debug/net6.0', there is a DLL I can use. However and in contrary of the bin folder, inside '[RepoName]/obj/Debug/net6.0' there is a DLL in the root ('net6.0') of that folder. Then you have two more directories inside 'net6.0':

1. ref
2. refint

Surprisingly, both of them contain another DLL...

As you can tell, **so many DLLs!**

I found one explanation in particular, but I just need to know which one of them to select 'when adding project references'. I feel like I must use the one from the bin folder due to having read the following, but I'm not sure:
[What are the obj and bin folders (created by Visual Studio) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for)

Which one of them should I use when adding 'Project references'? I'd appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DLL file**

In my opinion and based on the source I've mentioned earlier, it would probably be a good idea to use the DLL from the bin folder.. since the bin folder will be consisting of the final executable and compiled files.

**.csproj file**

Another way to solve this issue, is just to add an existing project instead of using the DLL file. Just choose the one with the extension that ends with [Project Name].csproj. It will hold a reference to that DLL file from the bin folder, ultimately it comes down to the same thing.

Hopefully, others can confirm what I've just said here in case others have the same question.