# C# program won't start outside visual studio as a .EXE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, json.net, exe

I have created a small program in C# WinForms that runs fine when I start it in Visual Studio 2017. But when I build the solution and double click the .exe, nothing happens, no screen appears, even the task manager doesn't see it. No errors. It's like it doesn't do anything! My only guess is that I built it wrong because I used Nuget to install newtonsofts JSON.NET in the solution. Do I need to do anything differently or should just building the solution work?

[solved]

today i learned the difference between the bin and obj folder, thanks to everyone for helping

Comment: Did you do a console application?

Comment: no, it's a winforms application

Comment: What is the name of the exe and what folder is it in?

Comment: I doubt that it is because of the json.NET Nuget Package. In that case many many users would have already filed bugreports.

Comment: Perhaps it helps if you write an exception handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `Application.ThreadException`. The handler should write the exception into a file. Maybe this helps to find out, what is going on.

Comment: Can you see the Application's name in Task Manager?

Comment: Did you check event log for exception, it may help you to narrow down exact issue your app has. Most probably missing dll or unhandled exception.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the correct exe and not the one that ends with `.vshost.exe`?

Comment: @Crowcoder the name is CrewBirthdayEditor.exe, and it is in the obj/debug folder of the project

Comment: @Fildor nope, it isn't in the taskmanager

Comment: @Vecro `bin\debug`? `bin\release`? Are you running the one that is built by your currently selected build configuration?

Comment: @Vecro - Don't run from obj\debug... that's for intermediate build files. Run from bin (Release, Debug, or whatever configuration you built it for).

Comment: For future reference, one good way of investigating console application issues when you see no console, is to start the application via Command Prompt, as it will launch your application in the console window and keep the output if it crashes. Alternatively pipe it out to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> it is in the obj/debug folder of the project

It sounds like you're running the wrong .exe. The `obj` folder is used for temporary/misc. files from the build process (see [What is obj folder generated for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172279/what-is-obj-folder-generated-for)).

Instead, you want to run the exe within `bin\Debug`, if "Debug" is the configuration you're building for. You can see which configuration at the top of VS.
[image]

Like others have also mentioned, make sure that Newtonsoft.Json.dll is being copied to that output directory as well. Programs and their dependencies need to be together, generally speaking. Otherwise, your exe will not know where to find the JSON code it needs to function.

99% of the time, you should pretend the `obj` directory isn't even there.

If that *still* isn't pointing you in the right direction, run the app from a command window. Any exception should get printed to it and the window will remain open for you to examine (and this has the benefit of not needing any additional logging or exception handling code to see this error).
For example, I wrote up a bad application that get a `NullReferenceException` in a method called `Test` that is called from `Main`. As you can see, the stacktrace is easily visible, even though my app has crashed (credit to ColinM for bringing this up originally).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there's a problem with the startup module. Follow the steps below

1. Open your Solution in visual studio
2. Double click on properties

   [image]
3. Select output type to Windows Application
4. Make sure to set the startup object as follows

   [image]

I hope it helps

Comment: Why would it run from Visual Studio if the project properties were wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, yet another reason (that I have experienced) can be

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert();
```

statements. In my case, the program executed normally when started from VS but when I run it by clicking its .exe (created in the Debug Mode) then it hung/freezed. No exceptions, no printed logs. Frustrating. Then I checked the Windows Event Viewer (Our true friend). It explicitly  displayed the problem and the culprit was a Debug.Assert() statement.

**The lesson learned again: Check**

**Windows Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application**

especially when your app hangs/freezes/deadlocks or when no app logs are available.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is only one reason

There is a [command line argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments) predefined in Visual Studio. Your application uses this argument to be executed, without it, it closes itself too quickly and you even can't see your application opened.

`Right click on your project in VS -> Properties -> Debug` and see if there is a value in  command line arguments

Comment: there is no value in the command line arguments, should there be? if so what should it be?

Comment: Since when do WinForms applications come with a predefined argument in that window?

Comment: +1 It happend to me that I just forgot about a command line parameter I had implemented and entered into the debug configurations.

Answer (score 1):

exe and their supporting files should be in the bin folder. Do not copy only exe from bin folder and try to run it. It is a good idea to write some exception code to get the detail.

Comment: @Vecro - I think he's telling you to make sure that supporting libraries (Newtonsoft.Json.dll) are also in the bin folder.